# Pandas resample() Series giving incorrect indexes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I am trying to bin a multi-year time series of dates and float values. I'm trying to aggregate each day in to 15 minute bins.  So I group the data set by day and then resample in 15 minute increments on each day.

The results seemed odd so I took a closer look at the behaviour of the resampling.  The code below summarizes the kind of results I observed (I run it in repl.it)

```
aindex = pd.to_datetime([
"2013-04-05 04:15:31",
"2013-04-05 05:15:18",
"2013-04-05 05:15:19",
"2013-04-05 05:15:19",
"2013-04-05 05:17:15",
"2013-04-05 07:06:31",
"2013-04-09 04:15:31",
"2013-04-09 05:15:18",
"2013-04-09 05:15:19",
"2013-04-09 05:15:19",
"2013-04-09 05:17:15",
"2013-04-09 07:06:31",
"2013-04-09 07:21:28",
"2013-04-09 09:18:19",
"2013-04-09 09:19:19",
"2013-04-09 09:21:31"])
a = pd.Series([-4.50e+08,
-4.80e+08,
-6.10e+08,
-5.80e+08,
-5.70e+08,
-5.710e+08,
-4.598432e+08,
-4.814140e+08,
-6.109284e+08,
-5.870819e+08,
-5.759888e+08,
-5.713363e+08,
-5.275122e+07,
-2.853787e+08,
-2.523782e+08,
-4.273267e+08],aindex)
print(a)
print(a.groupby(a.index).apply(lambda x: x))
print(a.resample("15T", base=0).apply(lambda x: x))
print(a.groupby(a.index).resample("15T").apply(lambda x: x))
```

'groupby' behaves as expected but note that each value of 'x' is type pd.Series. 'resample' also returns type pd.Series but appears to miss values when I display it in repl.it or Jupyter but if you change .apply(lambda x: x) to  .apply(lambda x: list(x)) you can see there are actually multiple values.  'groupby'+'resample' almost does what I expected ie. each day has 15 minute bins except the indexing is wrong anywhere a 'resample' returned more than one value.

I'm trying to understand what I'm seeing so I can apply the process with confidence.  Is this correct behaviour and if so why?

Note: To clarify a bit more my expectations.  If I look at the result of a resample for one day then resample includes empty bins:

```
2013-04-05 04:15:00   -450000000.0
2013-04-05 04:30:00            NaN
2013-04-05 04:45:00            NaN
2013-04-05 05:00:00            NaN
2013-04-05 05:15:00   -570000000.0
2013-04-05 05:30:00            NaN
2013-04-05 05:45:00            NaN
2013-04-05 06:00:00            NaN
2013-04-05 06:15:00            NaN
2013-04-05 06:30:00            NaN
2013-04-05 06:45:00            NaN
2013-04-05 07:00:00   -571000000.0
2013-04-05 07:15:00            NaN
2013-04-05 07:30:00            NaN
2013-04-05 07:45:00            NaN
2013-04-05 08:00:00            NaN
2013-04-05 08:15:00            NaN
2013-04-05 08:30:00            NaN
2013-04-05 08:45:00            NaN
2013-04-05 09:00:00            NaN
2013-04-05 09:15:00            NaN
2013-04-05 09:30:00            NaN
2013-04-05 09:45:00            NaN
2013-04-05 10:00:00            NaN
```

But if a groupby is done first I don't get empty bins.  Why not?:

```
...
2013-04-05 04:15:31  2013-04-05 04:15:00   -450000000.0
2013-04-05 05:15:18  2013-04-05 05:15:00   -480000000.0
2013-04-05 05:15:19  2013-04-05 05:15:00   -580000000.0
2013-04-05 05:17:15  2013-04-05 05:15:00   -570000000.0
2013-04-05 07:06:31  2013-04-05 07:00:00   -571000000.0
...
```

Comment: Because you are grouping by index, so basically you have one item per group. Then you are doing a resample on the index of the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resample is a tricky function. The main issue with the resampling is that you need to select which value you want to keep (using [`pandas.DataFrame.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html)).

So doing:

```
> a.resample("15T", base=0).last()

2013-04-05 04:15:00   -450000000.0
2013-04-05 04:30:00            NaN
2013-04-05 04:45:00            NaN
2013-04-05 05:00:00            NaN
2013-04-05 05:15:00   -570000000.0
```

would remove the need of using `.apply(lambda x: x)` since it will keep that last element from the sample.

`pandas.DataFrame` resample already uses `mean` as default.

To have an equivalent with `groupby`, you would need to do it is safer to group and then apply the mean so we can interpolate the value for the interval

```
> a.groupby(a.index).mean().resample("15T", base=0).last()


2013-04-05 04:15:00   -450000000.0
2013-04-05 04:30:00            NaN
2013-04-05 04:45:00            NaN
2013-04-05 05:00:00            NaN
2013-04-05 05:15:00   -570000000.0
```

I hope understood your question correctly. Let me know if it helps.

**Edit**

You could try to keep all the indices using:

```
> a.resample('15T').asfreq()
```

But you will get: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

This is the main issue, that indices in pandas cannot be duplicated. That is why `groupby` with a mean works, since it groups the items in groups of one elements and then resample for that group.

One way to accomplish this without `groupby`is using Multiindex dataframes:

```
> a.to_frame().set_index([a.index, a.index.round('15T')])

                                                   0
2013-04-05 04:15:31 2013-04-05 04:15:00 -450000000.0
2013-04-05 05:15:18 2013-04-05 05:15:00 -480000000.0
2013-04-05 05:15:19 2013-04-05 05:15:00 -610000000.0
                    2013-04-05 05:15:00 -580000000.0
2013-04-05 05:17:15 2013-04-05 05:15:00 -570000000.0
2013-04-05 07:06:31 2013-04-05 07:00:00 -571000000.0
2013-04-09 04:15:31 2013-04-09 04:15:00 -459843200.0
2013-04-09 05:15:18 2013-04-09 05:15:00 -481414000.0
2013-04-09 05:15:19 2013-04-09 05:15:00 -610928400.0
                    2013-04-09 05:15:00 -587081900.0
2013-04-09 05:17:15 2013-04-09 05:15:00 -575988800.0
2013-04-09 07:06:31 2013-04-09 07:00:00 -571336300.0
2013-04-09 07:21:28 2013-04-09 07:15:00  -52751220.0
2013-04-09 09:18:19 2013-04-09 09:15:00 -285378700.0
2013-04-09 09:19:19 2013-04-09 09:15:00 -252378200.0
2013-04-09 09:21:31 2013-04-09 09:15:00 -427326700.0
```

Or, altering the index order to group by the rounded index:

```
> a.to_frame().set_index([a.index.round('15T'), a.index])


2013-04-05 04:15:00 2013-04-05 04:15:31 -450000000.0
2013-04-05 05:15:00 2013-04-05 05:15:18 -480000000.0
                    2013-04-05 05:15:19 -610000000.0
                    2013-04-05 05:15:19 -580000000.0
                    2013-04-05 05:17:15 -570000000.0
2013-04-05 07:00:00 2013-04-05 07:06:31 -571000000.0
2013-04-09 04:15:00 2013-04-09 04:15:31 -459843200.0
2013-04-09 05:15:00 2013-04-09 05:15:18 -481414000.0
                    2013-04-09 05:15:19 -610928400.0
                    2013-04-09 05:15:19 -587081900.0
                    2013-04-09 05:17:15 -575988800.0
2013-04-09 07:00:00 2013-04-09 07:06:31 -571336300.0
2013-04-09 07:15:00 2013-04-09 07:21:28  -52751220.0
2013-04-09 09:15:00 2013-04-09 09:18:19 -285378700.0
                    2013-04-09 09:19:19 -252378200.0
                    2013-04-09 09:21:31 -427326700.0
```

Comment: Tnx!  That helps a lot I think.  Later in the processing I need to take the mean of _all_ the values so I can't do 'mean' at this stage BUT wherever I have a list of values followed by an empty series I need to populate the empty series with the last value from the list (unless the index is in the next day in which case it is populated with 0 ... kind of like 'fill' but with conditions.

Comment: Perfect! Good insight in to indexing.